# Mongodb remove objects from array that match multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

So my MongoDB document contains an array like this:

```
{
  prop: "val",
  items: [{
      prop1: "a",
      prop2: "b",
      prop3: "c"
    },
    {
      prop1: "d",
      prop2: "e",
      prop3: "f"
    },
    {
      prop1: "x",
      prop2: "y",
      prop3: "z"
    }]
}
```

And I get an array like this:

```
const toRemove = [{
  prop1: "d",
  prop2: "e",
  prop3: "f"
},
{
  prop1: "x",
  prop2: "y",
  prop3: "z"
}]
```

How do I remove the objects from the array in the document that matches all fields in the objects from the array?

I tried to do it multiple ways already, but it never works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really tricky to remove multiple elements that should match all properties,

You can use an update query with `$pull` operator, and `$or` operator to make sure all properties are exactly the same format,

```
const toRemove = [{
  prop1: "d",
  prop2: "e",
  prop3: "f"
},
{
  prop1: "x",
  prop2: "y",
  prop3: "z"
}];

db.collection.updateMany(
  {}, // write your query
  {
    $pull: {
      items: {
        $or: toRemove 
      }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j86u6otNQle)